# Exercise 4-K Program Ride Admittance Java homework

Tags: variables, if-statement, java.util.scanner, do-while

I was given a homework assignment that no matter how hard I try (searching Google, reading the textbooks, etc.) I cannot figure out how to properly nest these statements.

The Fair Grounds Ride Company has been having problems with people that do not meet height requirements getting on rides they should not be on. They need you to write a program to help with this problem. Upon entering the park each customer will get a wrist band of a certain color to indicate which rides they can go on.

If the customer is 36 inches tall or less they will receive a red band and be allowed to ride only slow rides like Turtle’s Slowing Spinning Shell.

If they are between 36 and 54 inches they will receive a yellow band and be allowed to ride moderately fast rides like Rabbit’s Bouncy Easter Egg.

If they are 54 to 80 inches tall they will receive a green band and be allowed to ride exciting rides such as Hindenburg: Jump for Your Life.

If they are over 80 inches tall they will receive no band as they are too tall to ride anything without hitting their head on something so they can just hang out in the Hall of Industry which is perfectly safe for everybody.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise4_K {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean moreRiders = true;
    String bandColor = "";

    while (moreRiders) {
        System.out.println("Please enter height in inches (or 0 to exit)");
        int height = scanner.nextInt();

        if (height == 0) {
            System.out.println("bye bye");
            moreRiders = false;
        } else {
            if (height > 80) {
                bandColor = "Sorry, too tall";
            } else if (height <= 36) {
                bandColor = "red";
            } else if (height <= 80) {
                bandColor = "yellow";
            } else if (height >= 54){
                bandColor = "green";
            System.out.println("")

                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Write a program that will accept a whole number of inches entered by the fair entrance gatekeeper and then print out the appropriate band color or “no band” as per the rules above.

Comment: I apologize ahead of time for being such a newbie. I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out some of these homework assignments and thought maybe I could find some help here.

Comment: Hi Jp, do you have any constraints by solving this homework? Like solving it with a while-loop?

Comment: We're actually on the subject of looping at the moment.

Comment: Ok forget my question. I was thinking way to complex. Your problem is more of another kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only saving the color in `bandColor` but never using it in `System.out.println`.
And you have to watch the order in which you write the if-else-conditions.

This should work:

```
while (moreRiders) {
        System.out.println("Please enter height in inches (or 0 to exit)");
        int height = scanner.nextInt();

        if (height > 80) {
            message = "Sorry, too tall";
        }
        else if (height >= 54) {
            message = "green";
        }
        else if (height > 36) {
            message = "yellow";
        }
        else if (height >= 1) {
            message = "red";
        }
        else if (height == 0) {
            message = "bye bye";
            moreRiders = false;
        }
        System.out.println(message);

        }
```

I also changed your `bandColor` to `message` because of the "bye bye"

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about adding lines that included  the types of rides they would be allowed on, could you show me one example of a return for that?

Comment: You just could add it to the string. Like `"Green - You can ride Hindenburg: Jump for Your Life"`.

Comment: If this solution works for you please accepted the answer as solved. :)

Comment: Thank you again!  I think sometimes I'm over-complicating things because I'm nervous about being so new at this. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm like that, too. But it gets better with time. :)